# Can I install a Windows Service with Wixsharp

Tags: wixsharp

I've been working with WIX# (wixsharp) for creating an MSI and I can't see how to install a windows service. I've gone through the whole CHM file but I'm not seeing anything specific for Windows Services.

TIA,

Brent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 1.0.4 (released 2015-01-18), WiX# supports installation of Windows services.

https://wixsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/610843

```
File service;
var project =
    new Project("My Product",
        new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\My Company\My Product",
            service = new File(@"..\SimpleService\MyApp.exe")));

service.ServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller
{
    Name = "WixSharp.TestSvc",
    StartOn = SvcEvent.Install,
    StopOn = SvcEvent.InstallUninstall_Wait,
    RemoveOn = SvcEvent.Uninstall_Wait,
};
```

Comment: I'm confused, why is the service a file object with a ServiceInstaller?